# Wire Mock - Spring Cloud Feign Integration Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wiremock, feign

I have a rest controller that talks with a service class, which calls the feign client. The spring application starts fine and works fine. Now I am trying to write integration tests for the spring feign client using wire mock; by following the guide from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-feign-integration-tests). When running the test, I am seeing Bean Currently in Creation exception. Could anyone tell me what am I missing?

Here is the wire mock config class:

```
@TestConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class WireMockConfig {
    @Autowired
    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public WireMockServer mockServer(){
        return new WireMockServer(options().dynamicPort());
    }
}
```

I stubbed the response as shown below:

```
public class DataMocks {
    public static void setUpTypesResponse(WireMockServer mockService) throws Exception{
        mockService.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/endpoint"))
                .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withHeader(Header.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withBody(
                                copyToString(
                                        DataMocks.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("payload/Response.json"),
                                        Charset.defaultCharset()))));
    }
```

Here is my integration testing class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WireMockConfig.class})
class DataFeignClientIntegrationTest{
    @Autowired
    private WireMockServer mockServer;

    @Autowired
    private FeignClient feignClient;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() throws Exception {
        DataMocks.setUpTypesResponse(mockServer);
    }

    @Test
    public void findTypesTest() throws Exception{
        RequestParams requestParams = RequestParams.builder().build();
        assertEquals(feignClient.findTypes(requestParams).getClass(),Response.class);
    }
```

The error is:

> Error creating bean with name 'wireMockConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to autowire the WireMockServer at the Config Class?

the config class is the one that your WireMockServer will be using.

Remove the following lines:

```
@Autowired
private WireMockServer wireMockServer;
```

and test